# How to colorize usernames on the joomla website depending on usergroups they belong to?

Tags: php, css, joomla

My website is based on Joomla CMS and it uses multiple extensions that work together such as Kunena forum, EasySocial etc to give my community great social experience. The community is centered around a game and we need to colorize our users differently based on which usergroup they belong to.

So, Kunena forum has its own coloring based upon forum permissions (Admin, Mod, Member, Banned, Visitor etc), EasySocial just like Facebook has just one default color for all users, same like Joomla in general. I tried to see if there is an option to colorize users for each Joomla Usergroup but such feature does not exist. Researched the internet for the solution, did not find anything. Found few similar or same questions with no useful replies. Asked on Joomla official support forum, did not receive any reply.

Now, I got the idea how to do this, but I'm not sure whether it can be done. Basically, how usernames are rendered is shown here:

```
<a alt="administrator" href="/community/profile/560-administrator">administrator</a>
```

or

```
<a class="kwho-admin" rel="nofollow" title="View administrator's Profile" href="/community/profile/560-administrator">administrator</a>
```

Would it be possible to modify the backend code in such way to have it add an ID to `<a>` element above depending on usergroups automatically, so we can set the colors with CSS as we like for each usergroup? (the class you see above inside "a" element is only present in forum, but not the whole website, thus making it no use for me in this problem)

I mean something like this as example:

```
<a id="usergroup1" class="kwho-admin" rel="nofollow" title="View administrator's Profile" href="/community/profile/560-administrator">
```

and then use CSS on usergroup1 ID to colorize it

```
#usergroup1{ color: black;}
```

If such thing is possible to alter in backend, I would really need some help because I'm not experienced in PHP.

Comment: don't use IDs for that. Better class.

Comment: ah I forgot that I can use multiple classes at once, yeah you're right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem being here is that not all extensions will add a class or alt attribute to the tag containing the username. For example, Kunena may render this:

```
<a class="kwho-admin" href="#">mistergeko</a>
```

where as Community Builder may render this:

```
<a href="#">mistergeko</a>
```

Notice that there is no class on the second instance, therefore how do you detect both?

If you only want to target 1 particular extension that renders the username, for example this:

```
<a class="kwho-admin" title="View administrator's Profile" href="#">administrator</a>
```

Then you can simply target this using the following CSS:

```
.kwho-admin {
    color: black;
}
```

Do not target usernames based on ID as you may for some reason change this in the future and forget to update your CSS. It's not a dynamic method and thus should not be done.

Comment: that class is based on permissions so even if i use that one it's no use for this purpose. But, generally speaking it would be awesome even if it's possible to do in just one extension (forum). If I knew a way in backend to go through usergroups for a user and append a class for each usergroup they find assigned to one user.Then it would render the username with those classes added and I could easily target it with CSS then.